Why Does God Need Another Holy Spirit For Himself?
Scripture tells us that God the Father is holy. We can say with certainty that God is Spirit, not human. Therefore, if God is holy And spirit, that makes Him The Holy Spirit. Why then would God need another Holy Spirit for Himself, if He is already The Holy Spirit?

This question is similar to: What role does the Holy Ghost fill that the Father can't?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

May I ask for a clarification? Are you asking if the Holy Ghost ministers to God the Father? Or are you asking if, from the perspective of the Trinity doctrine, since God the Father and the Holy Ghost are aspects of the same individual, why have different aspects? Or are you asking if, God the Father having a spirit already, and assuming the three aspects act independently (ignoring the Trinity doctrine, if you will), why have a second spirit when the spirit of God the Father will do? (It's the "...for Himself" part of your question that's confusing to me.)

Explain How, Philippians 2:6 & John 14:28 Can Simultaneously Both Be True???

The Holy Bible gives answers to all those points, so here are just a few examples that you may like to look up for yourself, to begin getting a clearer picture:
The Spirit of God moved over the dark waters of our newly created Earth, doing His work of bringing order out of chaos, light out of darkness. - Genesis 1:2
He creates us, equally as does the Father and the Son. - Job 33:4
The Holy Spirit anoints God's people and guides them; all Christians are anointed. - Psalm 139:7, Rom 8:1-17
To be without the Holy Spirit is a dreadful thing. - 1 Samuel 16:14, Psalm 51:11
The Holy Spirit inspired the writing of all of the Bible and gives the understanding of it. - John 15:26, 2 Peter 1:20
Jesus said that after he returned to heaven, he would send the Holy Spirit to Earth to indwell believers. - John 16:7
The only unforgivable sin is to blaspheme against the Holy Spirit.  You can only blaspheme a person, not a 'thing' (like electricity)! Jesus said we could be forgiven for speaking against himself, or the Father. - Mark 3:28-29
At Jesus' baptism, he was present in bodily form, the Holy Spirit appeared in the form of a dove, and the Father spoke from heaven. All three at that one occasion but the Father remained in heaven while the Holy Spirit alighted on Christ, on Earth. - Matthew 3:16-17
Before returning to heaven, Jesus commanded the disciples to go forth teaching / preaching and baptising in the singular name of Father, Son and Holy Spirit. One Name. Three Persons. - Matthew 28:19-20
There is so much more. If I made a list of everything the Bible says about the Holy Spirit it would run to pages. He is the third person in the Godhead - uncreated, co-equal with the Father and the Son.

Your question indicates you do not understand who and what the Holy Spirit is. Before attempting to answer your main question, here is a brief introduction about God (the Father), Jesus (the Son), and the Holy Spirit.
Introduction: There is only the One Being of God. A Divine Being is not to be confused with a human being. Also, God is Spirit. Before Jesus came to earth to born as a human, he existed in heaven alongside God (the Father) and the Holy Spirit (John 1:1-4).  Within the One Being of God subsist the three persons of Father, Son and Holy Spirit. Not three Gods.
Here is a brief description of the roles each play within the Godhead:

The Father is the ultimate source or cause of the universe (1 Corinthians 8:6; Revelation 4:11); divine revelation (Revelation 1:1); salvation (John 3:16-17); and Jesus' human works (John 5:17; 14:10). The Father initiates all of these things.


The Son is the agent through whom the Father does the following works: the creation and maintenance of the universe (1 Corinthians 8:6; John 1:3; Colossians 1:16-17); divine revelation (John 1:1, 16:12-15; Matthew 11:27; Revelation 1:1); and salvation (2 Corinthians 5:19; Matthew 1:21; John 4:42). The Father does all these things through the Son, who functions as His agent.


The Holy Spirit is the means by whom the Father does the following works: creation and maintenance of the universe (Genesis 1:2; Job 26:13; Psalm 104:30); divine revelation (John 16:12-15; Ephesians 3:5; 2 Peter 1:21); salvation (John 3:6; Titus 3:5; 1 Peter 1:2); and Jesus' works (Isaiah 61:1; Acts 10:38). Thus, the Father does all these things by the power of the Holy Spirit.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Trinity-Bible.html
Please read this article for full details on who and what the Holy Spirit is and his role within the godhead.
The answer to your question is that the Holy Spirit has been present with the Father and the Son since before time began. The Spirit is integral to all of the things that God is described as doing in the Bible. Jesus told His disciples that the Holy Spirit, the Helper, was different from Himself. The Father would send the Helper, the Spirit of truth, after Christ departed. The Spirit would speak through the disciples about Jesus (John 14:25–26; 15:26–27; 16:7–15).
All three Persons Jesus mentions — Father, Son, and Holy Spirit — are part of the One Being of God while being distinct from each other within the Trinity.

The question, “Why does God need another Holy Spirit for Himself?” seems to stem from a fundamental misunderstanding of the Christian doctrine of the Trinity. A biblical response can be provided through interpretive methods such as exegesis, contextual analysis, and the comparison of Scriptures.
1.Contextual Analysis: Understanding the Trinity
The doctrine of the Trinity teaches that God is one being in three persons: the Father, the Son (Jesus Christ), and the Holy Spirit. These three persons are co-equal, co-eternal, and consubstantial (of the same essence). God does not need "another Holy Spirit" because the Holy Spirit is God Himself at work in the world.
Key Verse:
“For there are three that testify in heaven: the Father, the Word, and the Holy Spirit, and these three are one.” (1 John 5:7, as found in some ancient translations)
This passage highlights the unity and harmony of the three divine persons. The Holy Spirit is not a separate or additional being but an eternal and essential person of the Godhead.
2.Exegesis of Texts About the Holy Spirit
The role of the Holy Spirit is often misunderstood. The Bible describes the Holy Spirit as the Spirit of God (Genesis 1:2) and as the one who fulfills God’s will. He is not an "addition" to God but an expression of His presence.
Examples:
“The Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.” (Genesis 1:2)
From the beginning of creation, the Spirit is active, showing that He is an integral part of God, not a separate entity.
“The Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in My name, will teach you all things.” (John 14:26)
Here, Jesus explains that the Spirit is not an addition but a manifestation of both the Father and the Son.
3.Comparison of Scriptures: God Is Perfect and Lacks Nothing
The Bible affirms that God is self-sufficient and perfect (Acts 17:25). He does not need anything to be complete. The Holy Spirit does not fulfill a need but acts as the expression of God’s presence in the universe.
Key Verse:
“Nor is He served by human hands, as though He needed anything, since He Himself gives to all mankind life and breath and everything.” (Acts 17:25)
4.Synthetic Response
God does not need "another Holy Spirit" because the Holy Spirit is part of God’s very nature. He is the Spirit of God, working in the world to accomplish His will. This understanding is rooted in the biblical doctrine of the Trinity, where the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are one and the same God.
If the question seems to suggest separation or addition to the Godhead, it should be reframed to recognize that God, in His eternal perfection, lacks nothing. The Holy Spirit is simply a manifestation of His power and presence in the world.
